# Android multiple alarms via AlarmManager and Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, alarmmanager

I am developing alarm application where user can create alarm for a certain time of the day + it is possible to choose days of a week for repeating the alarm.

At first, I tried using following code (but it was inaccurate, and alarm would sometimes fire 3-4 minutes later):

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        alarmIntent)
```

Now I am using following code (and it is precise, but it works one time only):

```
val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.hour)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.minute)
    set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
}
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        alarmIntent)
```

Now I am wondering what behaviour could I expect if I put `set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek)` in the code above (inside Calendar.apply).

Use case: 
User selects Monday and Thursday for firing alarm at 10am.

**My question:** Is it going to fire the alarm every Monday and Thursday at 10am (unless it is canceled) for every following Week or it's just going to fire alarm for current week?

P.S. I am asking because, maybe, someone has experience with this and I don't want to spend 2-3 weeks just testing this use case.

Comment: `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` will only fire once. In fact, any `set*()` method without `Repeating` in the name will only fire once. The date/time on your `Calendar` has no effect on that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. Any suggestions about this? In the documentation is is said: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. This means it won't fire the alarm at exact time, especially when device is in Doze mode. @MikeM.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you mean, how do you get repeating, exact alarms, you set the first one, and then when that fires, set the next one, and do so for each subsequent alarm until you need to stop.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that one but I thought it wasn't that good solution.

Comment: Nah, that's perfectly fine.